# Hidding a modal in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two modals, after I open **modal1** I have a button to open **modal2**. After **modal2** is open I have a close button in it, when I click it I want only **modal2** to close and keep showing **modal1**. This my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/PURQv/3/)**. I think `data-dismiss="modal"` is closing both.

```
<button class="btn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="javascript:;">Close</a>
</button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly ! `data-dismiss="modal"` is closing both. You have to remove it (and the link too) and to use javascript.

```
<button type="button" class="btn tt"  onclick="$('#stack1').modal('hide')">
    Close
</button>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/KckM9/3/